# Prevent Corona from caching my network requests

Tags: networking, lua, coronasdk

I couldn't find any information in the [documentation](https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/network/download.html) that mentions resources caching, but from my tests it seems like Corona caches files which is not what I wanted.

```
-- if this file has been downloaded before, Corona will be happy to ignore it
-- for me
network.request(some_url, "GET", network_handler, {
    filename = some_file_name,
    baseDirectory = system.CachesDirectory
})
```

As a web developer, I am used to dealing with browsers' caching shenanigans. Applying the same fix seems to fix the issue:

```
network.request(string.format("%s?_=%d", some_url, os.time()), "GET", network_handler, {
    filename = some_file_name,
    baseDirectory = system.CachesDirectory
})
```

This is definitely not optimal but I couldn't find any useful information in the documentation. Caching also seems to only affect downloading files. Normal network requests are not affected.

Any ideas on how to disable caching properly?

Comment: According to post [network.request cache](https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/16843-networkrequest-cache/) caching may depends on OS. Lucky shot: Specify headers paramater in request: `headers["Cache-Control"] = "no-cache"`.

Comment: @ldurniat That seems to have done the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [ldurniart](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7026995/ldurniat), it seems that adding

```
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

to the header forces the system to disregard the cache, though it ultimately depends on the system to decide.